# Name Our Chat Room

Tags: discussion, chat

Soon enough, I'm sure this site will have a chat room made somewhere by someone.  What should it be called?

EDIT:  Looks like we [already do](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/motor-vehicle-maintenance-and-repair).  Still, anyone want to suggest a rename?

Comment: I know this question was posted first, but I wanted a little more detail and reasoning for changing the name. I have merged the question so the suggestions could all be on one post.